# How to document a Builder with its methods using JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc, builder

I like to use the Builder pattern to instantiate objects of classes with complex states rather than using too many constructor arguments.

I can add a JavaDoc to the Class and each individual Method, but none of the JavaDoc keywords I know seems really fit to document the specificity of a builder, like what settings are mandatory, what are the defaults for optional settings.

If I document mandatory or optional and defaults for each individual method, it feels like the documentation is spread too much to get a global picture of it. Same if I document only the final `build()` method telling when it can build the instance with what defaults, and when it cannot.

None of these options seems really satisfying. It feels like JavaDoc does not fit so well with builder pattern but was designed for legacy Object Oriented code style; this or I don't understand it well enough.

I searched the https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html documentation but could not find an answer or guidance for documenting a Builder with proper tags.

`@param` looked like a valid candidate to document all the `setFoo`, `withBar`, `addBaz` from a builder at one place like the Builder class itself, but it seems not appropriate for this kind of usage.

How to properly document a Builder in JavaDoc or some other more appropriate tool?

Comment: if you have mandatory settings, shouldn't they be enforced by constructor or factory method, like [RestClient#builder(org.apache.http.HttpHost... hosts)](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/5.6.0/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.html#builder-org.apache.http.HttpHost...-)?

Comment: I work on modernizing and giving some fresh air on an old MinecraftForge mod, limited to Java8, and an awful code style. So there are objects with way too many states, way too many responsibilities. Replacing awfully long constructors with builders is one good improvement with maintaining deprecated methods for compatibility with surrounding closed source ARR mods. I mean, it is a community project and the margins for improvements are very wide, but the safe margin not to bring down the house of cards is very thin and not so many brains and surviving know about.

Comment: Kill 2 problems with one stone: problem 1: Generally speaking,  documentation in the form of comments is an anti pattern nowadays - you should name things well enough that they don't need documentation. The rare exception is particular nuances of a method contract. Problem 2: Don't write *any* code! Solution: Add Lombok's `@Builder` annotation to your class and you're done!

Comment: @LéaGris I believe you didn't get a point. If you have mandatory params you need to instantiate builder instance like `Builder builder(param1, param2)`,  doing that you automatically differentiate mandatory and optional parameters

Comment: There aren't any specific Javadoc tags for documenting builders, at least not provided by the default doclet. You could define your own tags, but that might be more work than it's worth. I would look at how other builders are documented (both in the JDK and in third-party libraries), and then use the approach that you like best.

Comment: @Bohemian I respectfully but vehemently disagree.  Method names can’t tell other developers constraints on arguments and return types.  Method names can’t explain the reasons for throwing particular exceptions.  Method names can’t expand on the meaning of industry-specific terms.  And Lombok is toxic garbage in my opinion;  it is the opposite of object-oriented development in more ways than I have room to list.

Comment: @vgr if you take the time to read my comment, you'll see I support comments for *method contract* nuances, which includes all the things you complain about. Not just methods, but parameters and exceptions also should self-explain by their names. As for Lombok... lol

Comment: @Bohemian Could you give an example of the kind of documentation you think is an anti-pattern? If you support documenting method contracts, including the parameters and exceptions, then I'm not sure I understand the first point of your first comment. I also think overly descriptive names is an anti-pattern itself (we have plain-language documentation for a reason).

Comment: @slaw if the method name is sufficient to imply its contract, do not add comments/doc. eg `Optional<Post> getMostRecentPost(int userId) throws NoSuchUserException` need no documentation or explanation of any kind. If a chunk of code needs comments, that a big red flag for breaking out the chunk into its own method and naming it with an terse version of the comments. btw, I reject PRs if there are comments that aren't absolutely needed due to peculiarities that can't be addressed by better naming of things. Add my teams haven't deployed any bugs for many, many years, so the pattern works.

Comment: @Bohemian That makes sense, though it's also basically just a getter method (regardless of how "complex" it is under the hood). Getters and setters are almost always straightforward. And I wouldn't consider that an overly descriptive name either. However, "proper" behavior methods (in the context of OOP) often, in my admittedly inferior experience, need more explanation (or otherwise a ridiculously long name).

Comment: @slaw that was just an example. At the very least the method should need minimal comments - that is, what *can* be implied by good naming should be (a method name like `findFirstPostExceptThoseMadeOnNewYearsEve()` is obviously ridiculous). Whatever remains that can't be simply implied by good naming warrants a comment. See [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: A more advanced form of the builder pattern is when you design fluent API. The drawback is that it will need a lot different interfaces. On the other hand, when you use the, API, the different interface types as return values will guide the user through the API. The IDE will offer only the methods that are usable at that point.

To ease the maintenance of these interfaces, I created a code generation tool, Java::, Geci, that can create them—using that the "grammar" of the fluent API is a "regular expression" over the methods, which itself is very readable documentation of the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already your first assumption ("I *can* add a JavaDoc to the Class and each individual Method, […]") is wrong.

Documentation is still mandatory, and it should be done as closely to the source as possible. A JavaDoc comment is *part* of the source, so it cannot be closer!

People telling you that comments are an "anti-pattern" nowadays do not have a clue or are too lazy to type or both – and when you read the source for that "anti-pattern" crap, you will find that it talks about *inline* comments explaining what's happening in your code, but not about *externalisable comments* for documentation purposes – so not about JavaDoc or Doxygen comments (or how the respective tools are named in other languages).

To your question: a builder class will be documented like any other class as well, with the keywords provided by JavaDoc and proper descriptive text. If you are too lazy to add this text manually, you can write your own extension to JavaDoc and define your own keywords that will generate that text for you.

Or you create your own `Annotation` and refer to that in the main description. My sample below does both (annotation and descriptive text), to give you an idea what I am talking about (the definition for the annotation `@IsMandatory` is omitted).

But usually, a `Builder` will not have methods for mandatory attributes; instead these are the arguments for the `Builder`'s constructor.

```java
/**
 *  <p>{@summary Builder for new instances of
 *  {@link MyObject}.}</p>
 *  <p>Attributes whose setter methods are marked with the
 *  {@link IsMandatory &#64;IsMandatory}
 *  annotation are – obviously – mandatory. If not set before
 *  {@link #build()}
 *  is called, an
 *  {@link IllegalStateException}
 *  will be thrown.</p>
 *  <p>In particular, these are the attributes</p>
 *  <ul>
 *    <li>{@link #setName(String) name}</li>
 *    … 
 *  </ul>
 */  
public final class MyObjectBuilder
{
  /**
   *  Creates a new instance of {@code MyObjectBuilder}.
   */
  public MyObjectBuilder() {…}

  /**
   *  Creates a new instance of
   *  {@link MyObject}.
   *
   *  @return The new instance.
   *  @throws IllegalStateException A mandatory attribute was not yet set.
   */
   public final MyObject build() throws IllegalStateException {…}

  /**
   *  <p>{@summary Sets the name for the new instance of
   *  {@link MyObject}.} It can be any arbitrary string with more than
   *  one character that is not
   *  {@linkplain String#isBlank() blank}.</p>
   *  <p><b>Note:</b> This attribute is mandatory! If missing,
   *  {@link #build()}
   *  will throw an
   *  {@link IllegalStateException}.</p>
   *
   *  @param name The name for the new instance.
   *  @throws NullPointerException {@code name} is {@code null}.
   *  @throws IllegalArgumentException {@code name} is the empty string, or
   *      it is
   *      {@linkplain String#isBlank() blank}.
   */
  @IsMandatory
  public final void setName( final String name ) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {…}

  /**
   *  Sets the other attribute for the new instance of
   *  {@link MyObject}.
   *
   *  @param other The other attribute.
   */
  public final void setOther( final Object other ) {…}
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and example supported explanation. It has been very helpful.